# ews authentication from liferay portlet

Tags: liferay, exchangewebservices, portlet

I am developing a Calendar Portlet using ews-java-api v.2 for our Liferay Portal.
When the user signed in in liferay, he shouldn't have to sign in again in Calendar portlet. 
But ExchangeService needs either username/password or securityToken to connect.
In liferay I have only the encrypted password(I cannot change it) and it is not useful for ews.

How should I generate the securityToken?
Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an user with specific permission for login and use the impersonation for acceding the user events.
[Configure impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722376(v=exchg.150).aspx)

and use in java like this way

```
ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService(...)
exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = 
                             new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, mailBox);
```